# Check for custom URL scheme in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, web, uri

I have an application that registers a new URL scheme when it's installed and I'm looking for a reliable way to launch this application from our web interface.

Right now I have an IFrame hidden away which I will update it's source after a button is clicked to launch the application, but it seems that in Internet Explorer the parent window always captures the URL scheme not recognized error and navigates to the location it can't understand anyway.

So my question: Is there a way for a programmer to check to see if a scheme is supported by a browser before attempting to navigate to the new URI to direct a user to download the application first?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check for URL schemes installed on the device.

What you can do is this:

```
setTimeout(function () { window.location = "appCustomUrlSchemeHere"; }, 25);
```

window.location = "fallbackUrlHere";

But I imagine that will still cause issues in IE as it will attempt to open the URL scheme.

Comment: I'd avoid this practice, seems pretty error prone (What if the location resolves in under 25ms? Do browsers even support modifying the location that quickly?) It would also still trigger IE's freak-out behavior, so this wouldn't solve much of anything.